# Jquery: Find all instances pattern in a string, prompt user for replacement for all instances of a pattern, then do a replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

So basically I am going to have a string, that will have n number of instance that match a pattern. Specifically, the pattern is going to be anything of this form <%=(text)%>.

I want to go through my string and fine every unique instance that matches that pattern. For example if my string looks like this.

```
<div>Stuff </div>
<%= url %>
<%= url %>
<%= name %>
<div>Stuff </div>
<%= name %>
<%= url %>
<%= name %>
```

I want to find the unique patterns <%= url %> and <%= name %>. I then want to prompt the user of my app for a replacement string for these matches. I.e. I want to a response insisting that <%= url %> be replaced with stackoverflow.com and   <%= name %> be replaced with Peter.

I then want to loop through the string and make these replacements. What is the best way/is this possible to do with Jquery and pure Javascript?

Comment: The most jQuery can do for you is get and set the html, and possibly replace the `prompt()` with a nicer looking dialog. The rest will have to be done with regexp and loops.

Comment: jQuery is not the hammer for every screw. This is something that seems to fit plain JS

Comment: Cool, what is the best way to do it with plain js?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var string = '<div>Stuff </div><%= url %><%= url %><%= name %><div>Stuff </div><%= name %><%= url %><%= name %>';

var n = document.getElementById('a');

function replaceWithPrompt(haystack) {
    if (!haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var nStr = haystack.replace(/(?:<\%\=\s+)(\b[\w]+\b)(?=\s+\%>)/gi, function(a,b) {
            var replaceWith = prompt('Replace "' + b + '" with: ', b) || b;
            return replaceWith;
        });
    }
    console.log(nStr);

}

n.onclick = function(){
    replaceWithPrompt(string);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PGLsG/).

The above is based on a page with the following mark-up:

```
 <button id="a">Replace the strings</button>​
```

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`window.prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3awindow.prompt).

Comment: Small change if the same replacement text should be used for every `<% name %>` (unclear to me from the Q, but that's what I'd want :) http://jsfiddle.net/meloncholy/z3QA8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// the original string
var string = "<div>Stuff </div><%= url %><%= url %><%= name %><div>Stuff </div><%= name %><%= url %><%= name %>​";

// array of patterns to substitute
var patterns = ["<%= url %>","<%= name %>"];

// ask for all the replacements
var result = replacePatterns(string, patterns);

// print out the result
console.log(result);

function replacePatterns(str, pat)
{
    for (var i in pat)
    {
        var p = pat[i];
        var regex = new RegExp(p, "g");
        var r = prompt("Replacement for "+p);
        str = str.replace(regex,r);
    }
    return str;
}
```